# A combination calculation with a twist

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

so I have a quiz with 10 questions.

Each question comes from a category with a specific number of questions (36, 21, 23, 17, 32, 19, 27, 15, 16, 13)

If each category is only used once in each quiz, how many different quizzes are possible?

I have looked, but the "stars and bars" solution is incorrect and so I am now not sure and my stats was a LONG time ago.!

So wanted to try the permutations ie n! / (n - m)! but excel on my mac will not exceed 170! ...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply [Rule of Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) and the answer should be
$$36\cdot 21\cdot 23\cdot 17\cdot 32\cdot 19\cdot 27\cdot 15\cdot 16\cdot 13 = 15139812280320$$
Stars and bars is not used here because we don't have identical questions in each category. Stars and bars is used when we have identical objects and we group them.

Comment: Thanks - tried to make it too complicated...

Comment: You're welcome :)